# Java not deterministic?

Tags: java

I've written a little predator-prey simulation in Java. Even if the rules are quite complicated and end up in a chaotic system the techniques used are simple:

- arithmetics and decisions on basic data types
- no external libraries
- no external systems are included
- no concurrency occurs
- no use of current time or date

So I thought when initializing the system with identical parameters it should output identical results, but it doesn't and I wonder why.

Some thoughts on that:
My application uses `Random`s, but for that test I initialize them all with a given value, so in my understanding they should create for every run the same outputs in the same order.

I'm iterating through `Set`s, and I know that the order a `Set` is iterated isn't defined. But I don't see any reason why a `Set` that is filled in the same order with the same values should behave different in several runs. Does it?

I'm using a lot of `float`s. Datatypes where 1 + 1 = 1.9999999999725 are always suspect to me, but I even if their behavior is strange to me, it should be always the same strange. Isn't it?

Garbage Collection isn't deterministic, but as long as I don't rely on destructors I should be safe.

As said above, there is no concurrency and no datatypes depending on the actual time in use.

I can't reproduce that behavior in a simple example. But going through my code, I can't see anything that could be unpredictable. So are any of my assumptions above wrong? Any ideas what I could be missing?

Here's a test to verify my assumptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random(1);
    Set<Float> s = new HashSet<Float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        s.add(r.nextFloat());
    }

    float ret = 1;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (Float f : s) {
        float multiply = 0.3f;
        if (cnt++ % 2 == 0) {
            multiply = 0.7f;
        }
        float f2 = (f * multiply);
        ret += f2;
    }

    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

It results always in 242455.25 for me.

Comment: When you say you initialize your random data, do you mean you use a seed?

Comment: This sounds interesting. May we have a look at your code?

Comment: `But I don't see any reason why a Set that is filled in the same order with the same values should behave different in several runs. Does it?` Don't rely on that. In Python, after [bug 13703: Hash collision security issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703) and in [Perl after 5.8.1](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/pod/perldelta.pod#Hash_Randomisation), dict/hashmap and sets are randomized due to security concerns, invalidating long-time false assumptions that dictionary/sets would have the same order between runs. Java is also vulnerable to the same issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write a deterministic program in Java.  You just need to eliminate the possible sources of non-determinism.

It's hard to know what could be causing non-determinism without seeing your actual code, and concrete evidence of that determinism.

There are any number of library methods that could potentially be sources of non-deterministic behaviour ... depending on how you use them.

For example, the value returned by `Object.hashcode()` (the first time it is called on an instance) is non-deterministic.  And that percolates through to any library that uses hashing.  It can definitely affecting the order in which elements of a `HashSet` or `HashMap` are returned when you iterate them ... if the element class doesn't override `hashcode()`.

Random number generators may or may not be deterministic.  If they are pseudo-random and they are initialized with fixed seeds, then the sequence of numbers produced by each one will be deterministic.

Floating point arithmetic *should* be deterministic.  For any (fixed) set of inputs to an arithmetic expression, the result should always be the same.  (I'm not sure that determinism of floating point arithmetic is guaranteed by the JLS, but it would be mighty strange if it happened in practice.  As in ... you are running on broken hardware.)

---

**FOLLOWUP** ... on `strictfp` and non-determinism.

According to the [JLS 15.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4):

> *"Within an expression that is not FP-strict, some leeway is granted for an implementation to use an extended exponent range to represent intermediate results; the net effect, roughly speaking, is that a calculation might produce "the correct answer" in situations where exclusive use of the float value set or double value set might result in overflow or underflow."*

This doesn't exactly say *how much* "leeway" the implementation has in a non-FP-strict expressions.  However, I'd have thought that that leeway would not extend to allowing non-deterministic behaviour.  I'd have thought that a JIT compiler on a particular platform would always generate equivalent native code for the same expression, and that code would be deterministic.  (I can't see any reason for non-determinism ... unless the hardware itself has non-deterministic floating point.)  The other possible source of non-determinism might be that behaviour of JIT compiled and interpreted code might be different.  But frankly, I think that it would be "nuts" to allow that to happen ... and I think we'd have heard of it.

So while non-FP-strict expression evaluation could be non-deterministic in theory, I think we should discount this ... unless there is clear evidence that it happens in practice.

(Note that I'm talking about real non-determinism, not platform differences.)

Comment: Determinism of floating point arithmetic isn't guaranteed without using `strictfp` - but that should only be across platforms. (+1)

Comment: Without `strctfp`, the implementation is free to sometimes use higher precision and sometimes not.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Yea.  Variability across platforms is not the same thing as non-determinism.  If you had true non-determinism, then your fp hardware is flawed ... if not broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - what implementation are you talking about?  The compiler?  The hardware?

Comment: You're right. Adding hashcode and equals to the classes stored in Collections did the trick

Comment: @StephenC: I mean the implementation of the Java compiler and run time, regardless of what components it consists of.

Comment: +1 for letting me know that Object.hashcode() is non-deterministic!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Yes.  I suppose that is true.  However, no real Java implementation behaves like that AFAIK.

Answer (score 11):

> I'm iterating throu Sets, and I know that the order a Set is iterated isn't definied. But I don't see any reason why a Set that is filled in the same order with the same values should behave differnet in several runs. Does it?

It can. The implementation is free to use, for example, the object's location in memory as the key into the underlying hash table. That can vary depending on when garbage collection runs.

Comment: @MichaelBulla - What JVM are you using?

Comment: @tjameson: I'm not using any particular JVM. This question is about what *can* happen, not what does happen.

Comment: It seems to be a "does happen" question, and I was hoping that if the OP lets us know what JVM he uses, we could look up implementation notes and see if this is potentially caused by the implementation.

Comment: Java 1.6_33 32bit on Win 7 64 bit

Comment: If it was a "does happen" question, I don't think he would ask about what was "safe". Safety is about what *can* go wrong, not what does go wrong. It's not safe to cross the street without looking both ways, no matter what *does* happen when you do it.

Comment: I don't see how knowing the platform is going to help here.  The problem is most likely in some assumption that the program is making, and that assumption is *likely* to be incorrect for all mainstream platforms.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Strictly speaking, the identity hashcode is not the objects location in memory.  Rather, it is typically *based on* the location at the time when `System.identityHashcode(Object)` is called.  If the object is relocated, the identity hashode does not change.

Comment: @StephenC: I can't imagine how you could make such a scheme work well. If the object moves and then another object gets its original location and is then assigned a hashcode, Couldn't it get the same hash? (Not that that would be fatal, but it sounds like it would suck.) But, in any event, I don't care about how particular implementations happen to do things, so long as they work. I care about what you can and cannot rely on because that's what can break your code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - *"I can't imagine how you could make such a scheme work well."*.  Trust me.  You can, and it does. *"If the object moves and then another object gets its original location and is then assigned a hashcode, couldn't it get the same hash?"* - Yes it can.  But that's not a problem.  It is a hash code ... not a unique identifier.

Comment: @StephenC: Imagine a pathological pattern where you allocate a small object, add it to a collection, then enlarge the object moving it to a new address making the original address available again, then repeat getting the same address because there's a recently freed block the perfect size. Every object may have the same address at the time it's added to the collection. I would consider such a design extremely poor, though it wouldn't surprise me that someone would do things that way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - It would be extraordinarily difficult to make that happen in Java.  For a start, you would need to garbage collect between each object creation.  Next, you would need to get very luck for the same address to keep appearing as the "next free address".  I don't think this is a realistic / plausible scenario.